# No se me agregan todas las tablas en el modelo de EntityFrameworkCore 7

Tags: entity-framework-core, blazor

Estoy probando `blazor wasm` con `NetCore 7` con cuentas individuales `sobre SQL Server`.

Ejecuto la aplicación la primera vez, me sale el mensaje diciendo que hay que aplicar la migración, genera las tablas, registro un usuario, todo bien.

Pero quiero acceder a las tablas de los usuarios para gestionar los permisos:

1. Me voy al sql server, abro la tabla `AspNetRoles` y agrego unos Roles
2. Me voy al sql server, abro la tabla `AspNetUserRoles` y agrego unas filas con los Roles y los Usuarios
3. Genero el modelo en Nugenat:

   Scaffold-DbContext "Server=servidor\bbdd;Initial Catalog=prueba7;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=password;Encrypt=False" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Force

Y el modelo que se genera está incompleto, no me trae todas las tablas en concreto la tabla "`aspnetuserrole`"

¿Cómo fuerzo a que agregue esta tabla?

Answer (score 0):

Pues resulta que al ser la tabla aspnetuserrole una tabla con relación muchos a muchos no genera la tabla en el modelo, por lo que se podría obtener los roles de un usuario así:

```
    AspNetUser usuario = _context.AspNetUsers.First(p => p.Email == idUser);
    List<AspNetRole> roles = usuario.Roles.ToList();
```

Pero a mi no me devuelve los roles, así que los he sacado así:

```
    AspNetUser usuario = _context.AspNetUsers.First(p => p.Email == idUser);
    var user = _userManager.Users.First(p => p.Id == usuario.Id);

    bool esUsuario= await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "Usaurio");
```